# Setting up Qt for use in a project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am trying to use Qt to make a simple GUI program in C++ using Microsoft Visual Studio.

Would anyone be able to walk me through how to get things up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently installed and used QT at home using VS19 Community and latest QT Open Source.

The following YouTube video should help you get started.

- [Configure VS19 to create QT5 Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bXrfVrYyxk&list=PLNanYGZ9Eha1PyIfvaXKO-GNj9TIwA7Du&index=5)

**The Summary:**

1. Install QT: Choose advanced, and install the latest version of QT + the support for version of Visual Studio you are using.
2. Install the "QT Visual Studio Tools" extension via the Visual Studio "Manage Extensions"
3. After installed, From inside VS, set the QT version under the Extensions-->QT VS Tools-->QT Options.
4. Create a new project.
   -- Search for "QT" as it may not appear in the list.

And you're off.